# Selecting child component with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I am able to select the child component easily with Enzyme but I would like to use react-testing-library. Suppose I have a component that returns the following:

```
return (
  <DropdownButton>
    <Dropdown.Item data-testid='x' key={id} />
  </DropdownButton>
)
```

As of now in a test I can easily select the `Dropdown.Item` with `const item = wrapper.find(Dropdown.Item)` but how come I cannot select via `const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />)` and `const item = getByTestId('x')` using react-testing-library and data-testid?

Should I be using a different query?

Comment: Testing-library is built around asserting the end dom rather than components. What you want is against the principles of `testing-library` https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles

Comment: @johnnypeter ahh so I was viewing it for something it is not - thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment above, react-testing-library "[...should deal with DOM nodes rather than component instances, and it should not encourage dealing with component instances](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles)". I was approaching this with the wrong view.

Thanks to *johnny peter* for the clarification.